# VIM Delete From Cursor to Another Location in File

Tags: vim, vi

I'm trying to learn VI/VIM.  I would like to know how to deleted the text from my cursor to some other spot in the file. I know how to delete a line (dd) and multiple lines (5dd) and to the end of a line (d$), but not, for example, from the cursor to the middle of the next line or the middle of the next two or three lines.

Thanks for any tips.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any motion after a `d`. For example, to delete two words, you can do `d2w`. Or to delete 10 characters to the left, you can do `d10h`, or to delete next two lines, do `d2j`. For something more complicated like 'delete up to middle of next line', I usually just do `v` to go into selection mode, select what I need with hjkl, and hit `d` to delete it. If you do block selection mode `Ctrl+v` you can select a block that needs deletion and hit `d`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers answers.  I have used the v for visual mode, but did not think of using for this (newbie brain block) I just tried it and it works great.    Thanks, all!!

Comment: answers answers => GREAT answers.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "the middle"?

You delete with `d{motion}`, and that includes things like:

```
d5w - delete the next 5 words
d/test - delete up to the word test
```

see

```
:help d
:help motion
```

and the motion.txt linked in the help (also online http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html )

Answer (score 0):

I used to have vi macros to delete between marks. e.g. use `ma` to make mark a, and then put your cursor where you want it and:

`mb'a"ad'b` will make mark b and delete from mark a to b into buffer 'a'

`mb'a"ay'b` will copy (not delete)

`"ap` will get the text back.

(from memory this is whole line based, not "position on a line")